# Performance for mongo aggregation query with match (2 fields) and sort (1 fields from matching)

Tags: mongodb

I have a lot of records in mongo database. And I try to perform aggregation query.
My query is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {
    "$match": {
       "$or": [
          {
             "field1": {
                "$regex": ".*\\Q...\\E.*", // where ... - any text
                "$options": "i"
             }
          },
          {
             "field2": {
                "$regex": ".*\\Q...\\E.*", // where ... - any text
                "$options": "i"
             }
          }
       ]
    }
 },
 {
    "$sort": {
       "field1": 1
    }
 },
 // another operations, such as limit, skip
])
```

But I have a problem, this matching is very slow.
I have following indexes:

```
{
   "field1": 1
}


{
   "field2": 1
}

{
   "field1": 1,
   "field2": 1
}
```

But when I remove match for field2 this query works faster

In all my cases the regex in match the same for field1 and field2, therefore I try to unite this field into one field as field1AndField2 on the application level and add index for this field. Also this works slow, but when I use this field in sort, the query works faster, but I can't use this field in sort, it's affect final result.

Do you have any idea about this issue?

**UPDATE 07.06**

Added explain of the aggregation query with compound index:

```
{
  "stages": [
    {
      "$cursor": {
        "query": {
          "$or": [
            ... // or with two fields
          ]
        },
        "sort": {
          ... // sort with field1
        },
        "queryPlanner": {
          ...
          "parsedQuery": {
            "$or": [
              ... // or with two fields
            ]
          },
          "winningPlan": {
            "stage": "SUBPLAN",
            "inputStage": {
              "stage": "FETCH",
              "filter": {
                "$or": [
                  ... // or with two fields
                ]
              },
              "inputStage": {
                "stage": "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern": {
                  "field1": 1,
                  "field2": 1
                },
                "indexName": "...", // index name
                "multiKeyPaths": {
                  "field1": [],
                  "field2": []
                },
                ...
                "indexBounds": {
                  "field1": [
                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                  ],
                  "field2": [
                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "rejectedPlans": []
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What does explain() tell you, e.g.:
`aggregate([ your pipeline ], {explain:true})`
If you are not seeing 2 input stages for the OR both using IXSCAN, then something else is going on.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Thank you for your interest. I updated my question with additional information, which contains explanation about the aggregation query with compound index for field1 and field2. If you want more additional information, please notify me about this.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try by changing $or and $match positioning?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
     {
      "$or": [
        {
          "$match" : {
            "field1": {
              "$regex": ".*\\Q...\\E.*", // where ... - any text
              "$options": "i"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            "field2": {
              "$regex": ".*\\Q...\\E.*", // where ... - any text
              "$options": "i"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
     },
     {
        "$sort": {
           "field1": 1
        }
     },
     // another operation, such as limit, skip
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But it's leads to error : unrecognized pipeline stage name '$or'